# what is the right meaning of "The most important thing of being rich is helping others"?

Tags: grammar, expressions

Is it asking about the most important ting for the rich or the process to be rich? What role do "being" play in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The writer is making a value statement - he or she is stating that rich people should help others.  The use of "being" is colloquial, and emphasizes that is is the state of (already) having wealth that makes it important to help others.  If you wanted to say that helping others is part of "the process to be rich", you would write "the most important thing to *become* rich is helping others".

Answer (score 0):

The whole statement could be rephrased to read;- The most wonderful part of having great wealth, is that it enables me/you/us to help other people.

> In this context   [**Being**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/being)      b (1) : something that is conceivable and hence capable of existing (2) : something that actually exists (3) : the totality of existing things

Comment: I agree with your rephrase but not with your linked meanings. I think that "being" is used here as a gerund-noun of the verb to be. But I haven't found the exact description of the structure (being + adjective).